# Xamarin Forms - set stack layout padding using a binding to a ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

How can I bind the padding of a stack layout to a value in a ViewModel?

```
<StackLayout x:Name="AddressStack" Padding="54.5,0,0,0" >
```

If the device is a phone I want to reduce the padding to 34.5,0,0,0

In the ViewModel I currently have what's below, just unsure how to wire it up correctly

```
private double _padding;
public double Padding
{
    get
    {
        return _padding;
    }
    set
    {
        if(Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
        {
            _padding = 34.5;
        }
        if(Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
        {
            _padding = 54.5;
        }
    }
}
```

Either that, or I could use something similar to how I set the font based on the platform:

```
<Label.FontFamily>
     <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
         <On Platform="iOS" Value="HelveticaNeue-Roman" />
         <On Platform="Android" Value="HelveticaNeue-Roman.otf#HelveticaNeue-Roman" />
     </OnPlatform>
</Label.FontFamily>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I answer your question, please read the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding).
Not recommended way, since it should not belong to `ViewModel`:

```
Thickness _padding;
public Thickness Padding
{
    get => _padding;
    set
    {
        if(Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
            _padding = new Thickness (34.5);
        if(Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
            _padding = new Thickness (54.5);
    }
}
```

But why to put it int he ViewModel when you can define it in XAML itself?

```
<StackLayout x:Name="AddressStack">
    <StackLayout.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="0,20,0,0" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,30,0,0" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </StackLayout.Padding>
</StackLayout>
```

or

```
<StackLayout x:Name="AddressStack">
    <StackLayout.Padding>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,20,0,0" Android="0,20,0,0" WinPhone="0,20,0,0" />
            </OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,30,0,0" Android="0,30,0,0" WinPhone="0,30,0,0" />
            </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
    </StackLayout.Padding>
</StackLayout>
```

More about [Thickness](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Thickness/).

Comment: I saw your edit thanks, can this be used in a similar way to evaluate the device type rather than the platform?  I couldn't figure that out in XAML

Comment: Ohh, I see. Updated my answer again.

Comment: I would definitely recomment the XAML way, paddings don't belong into the viewmodel, they are not view logic in the mvvm sense.

Comment: @Mafii totally agree, just mentioned it in the answer as well.